# Add UIImageView into UIScrollview dynamically, but it cannot autoresizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am already try to add `UIImageView` into `UIScrollView` dynamically, but it cannot autoresizing.

Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80 , 50)];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth ;
scrollview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[scrollview addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: The image is exist, but it just not autoresizing. 

Before: (width=80,height=50)
After:(width=80,height=50)

Autoresizing is not work.

Comment: your imageview frame is fixed here then how can you say that it is dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give AutoResizingMask as following :

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
```

You need to give remaining AutoResizingMasks values for required behavior. Here you need flexible Width & Height. So you need to give resizing mask values remaining four Margins.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead, you can do in alternative way. Create Image view with Respective Width and Height as per Device Size like below :  `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-50, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -100)];`

Comment: Thanks, it is work. But I don't know why my code is not work. I want to figure it out.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, then select it as CORRECT

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `UIView' in scrollview and then add your image view to this view. It may solve your problem.

Comment: Tried and it still cannot autoresizing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code you are create object of **imageView** and ading

```
[scrollview addSubview:imageView1];
```

**imageView1**

Comment: Sorry for my typo, [scrollview addSubview:imageView1]; should be corrected as [scrollview addSubview:imageView];.

Comment: Nope, it can be show, but it just cannot be autoresizing.

Comment: i have tried your code it shows me image on top left corner with passed width and height

Comment: I have not use Auto Layout in interface builder, so I want to use autosizing to resize the image, let it bigger and keep the ratio.